# get records group by some column and dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

am trying to get the records by group by guid and wants to get the max of date if the records are available for that date other wise wants to get min records if available for the next available day.

Table:

```
guid         startdate          enddate         id  xyz aaa bbb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
guid1   07-03-2023 00:00    07-03-2023 02:00    1   sd  dd  cv
guid1   07-03-2023 00:02    07-03-2023 04:00    1   das fd  rt
guid1   07-03-2023 04:00    07-03-2023 06:00    1   ds  yuy ff
guid2   07-03-2023 00:00    07-03-2023 01:00    1   yuy tr  juy
guid2   07-03-2023 01:00    07-03-2023 05:00    1   j   yut po
guid2   13-03-2023 01:00    13-03-2023 15:00    1   ewe dfs g
guid2   21-03-2023 04:00    24-03-2023 05:00    1   hj  lk  er


input to query is '2023-3-8 00:00:00'   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
guid2   13-03-2023 01:00    13-03-2023 15:00    1   ewe dfs g
                        
input to query is '2023-3-7 00:00:00'       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------               
guid1   07-03-2023 04:00    07-03-2023 06:00    1   ds  yuy ff
guid2   07-03-2023 01:00    07-03-2023 05:00    1   j   yut po
                        
input to query is '2023-3-20 00:00:00'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                        
guid2   21-03-2023 04:00    24-03-2023 05:00    1   hj  lk  er
                        
input to query is '2023-3-26 00:00:00'  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                   
nothing
```

Tried group by query but its breaking one or other case tried with min , max functions but not worked out for me. any help appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM   DATAS
WHERE  id= 1
AND    startdate = 
( 
SELECT Min(startdate) 
FROM   DATAS
WHERE  id = 1
AND    startdate >= '2023-3-7')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single scan of the base table, by using window functions and a bit of math. You just need to number the rows by the absolute difference (non-negative) from the @startdate + 1

```sql
DECLARE @date datetime = '2023-03-08';

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY guid ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, @date, DATEADD(day, 1, startdate)))),
      hasSameDay = COUNT(CASE WHEN startdate < DATEADD(day, 1, @date) THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY guid)
    FROM DATAS d
    WHERE d.startdate >= @date
) d
WHERE rn = 1
  AND (startdate < DATEADD(day, 1, @date)
       OR hasSameDay = 0);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/j0bPc0Hh)